# Can an EC2 instance with an IAM role still do AssumeRole?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, roles

I'm aware that an EC2 instance cannot assume two IAM roles at the same time. But how does STS AssumeRole fit into this? If my instance already has a role attached, can it still do AssumeRole?

I have an instance sending hundreds of requests per second to DynamoDB, and it has a role to be able to communicate with DynamoDB. Now I need to get data from S3, a couple of times per second. Can I use AssumeRole to get temporary credentials to access S3, only for the requests to S3 (if there is such a thing), or do I need to modify the existing role, adding permissions to access S3? I would prefer to avoid this second option.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear how to use assume role in an instance?

Answer (score 0):

> If my instance already has a role attached, can it still do AssumeRole?

Yes, but you have to **explicitly call** `AssumeRole` from your application. And also the existing **instance role** must have permissions to actually `AssumeRole`.

> Can I use AssumeRole to get temporary credentials to access S3,

Yes, but as explained you have to explicitly assume the role and the **current instance role** must have permissions to do so.